# Spring security missing select with join statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement spring security into [my app](https://github.com/Hyperxion/warehouse-manager) based on [this example](https://github.com/hellokoding/hellokoding-courses/tree/master/springboot-examples/springboot-security-login-thymeleaf). However, I am not able to log in, only when I register and it does autologin. When I want to login after logout, example application performs this statements:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_,
user0_.password as password3_1_, user0_.username as username4_1_ 
from user user0_ where user0_.username=?

Hibernate: select roles0_.users_id as users_id1_2_0_, 
roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, 
role1_.name as name2_0_1_ 
from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id 
where roles0_.users_id=?
```

On the other hand, my applicaiton performs only this statement:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_, 
user0_.password as password3_1_, user0_.username as username4_1_ 
from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
```

Something is missing there and i cant figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do the roles not load, the user is not found. Because `UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername` gets an empty username.

In `login.html` change:

```
<input autofocus="true" name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
```

into:

```
<input autofocus="true" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
```

Comment: didn't help, still only one select

Comment: And the one select doesn’t join the roles table? Odd.

Comment: you was right. I did renamed all fileds, columns, everything from username (as it was in example) into nickname. Because I wanted nickname. Then renamed it back and forgot this one + other one. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Add "@JoinColumn(name = "col_name")" To where you have your ManyToMany Mappings.

Comment: there is already "@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")" in "Role" entity. It refers to roles in User entity where there is "@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)"

Comment: I always do this and it works. 
@ManyToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "col_name")